# How I do SQL Pivot with respect to given query?

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on SQL Server 2012. Trying to `Pivot` table data.

I have tried below following Query,

```
SELECT CategoryName, 1996_Val, 1997_Val
FROM(  
SELECT  
Categories.CategoryName,  
Sum(CONVERT(money,("Order Details".UnitPrice*Quantity*(1-Discount)/100))*100) AS Sales,  
YEAR(Orders.ShippedDate) AS ShippingYear  
FROM Orders  
INNER JOIN [Order Details] ON Orders.OrderID = [Order Details].OrderID  
INNER JOIN Products ON [Order Details].ProductID = Products.ProductID  
INNER JOIN Categories ON Products.CategoryID = Categories.CategoryID  
WHERE (((Orders.ShippedDate) Between '19960101' And '19971231'))  
GROUP BY Categories.CategoryID, Categories.CategoryName,YEAR(Orders.ShippedDate)  
)p  
PIVOT  
(MAX(Sales) For ShippingYear IN(1996,1997)) AS pvt  
ORDER BY Categories.CategoryID
```

which didn't work. Please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got the pivot a bit wrong. I think it should look something like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
SELECT 
    Categories.CategoryName,
    YEAR(Orders.ShippedDate) AS ShippingYear,
    CONVERT(money,([Order Details].UnitPrice*Quantity*(1-Discount)/100))*100 as Sales
FROM 
    Orders  
INNER JOIN [Order Details] ON Orders.OrderID = [Order Details].OrderID  
INNER JOIN Products ON [Order Details].ProductID = Products.ProductID  
INNER JOIN Categories ON Products.CategoryID = Categories.CategoryID  
WHERE (((Orders.ShippedDate) Between '19960101' And '19971231'))
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Sales)
    FOR CategoryName IN ([Confections],[Meat/Poultry],
                         [Beverages],[Grains/Cereals],[Seafood])
) AS pvt
```